# Exporting Derby database in Netbeans

Tags: java, database, netbeans, derby

I have a project with a derby database in it.

I want to be able to make a backup or export the database so I can give it with the project files to my lecturer.

Comment: Embedded? Just give the database file.

Comment: Can you tell me where that file is located? thanks

Comment: @Steven From database administration you can take backup of DB files. [Backup and Restore MySQL Database Using mysqldump](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/)

Answer (score 5):

By default, the database resides in your home folder under `.netbeans-derby` (this folder may be hidden under Windows). Copying this folder will work, but your lecturer will have to "register" this copied location with his IDE. To do this:

- Under `Services`, open the `Databases` node.
- Right-click on `Java DB` and select properties.
- In the `Database Location` field, enter the path to the copied folder.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of ways to backup and/or export data in a Derby database: here's a link to the docs: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/adminguide/cadminparttwo.html

In order to make the backup, you have to find the database data on disk. It will all be located in a single folder/directory; that folder/directory is named using the name of your database. So if your database is jdbc:derby:brydb, look for a folder named 'brydb'.

Answer (score 3):

Late, but it may be useful for others:

1. In Netbeans, start a connection to your database.
2. Right click on it and select 'Execute command'
3. Write this:
   `CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_TABLE
   (null, 'YOURTABLE', 'PATHTODUMPFILE', null, null, null)`

Remember to write the name of your table and path between simple quotation marks ' '

More information in http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/adminguide/radminimport91458.html

Answer (score 1):

For 2017 NetBeans.

Let me suggest how to export sql scripts' file(after connection to db).
So that,go to

**1. Services -> Data base -> link -> Schema ->tables -> MYDB.**

**2. Rightclick on MYDB and select 'Browse data'. And then click 'execute sql' 
 first icon/button**

**3. In the list of rows below rightclick any of them, and choose "Show scenario for Create.." Sometimes output/logs window may overlay that list though. In such case close it please.**

**4. Copypast(cntrl-c,cntrl-v) instruction from popup window  to a prepared by you previously txt file**

**5. Again click  any of bottom list's rows. Select all of them  by cntrl-a keys' combination.  Rightclick and select "Show scenario for INSERT.."**

**6. Copy instruction from popup window and past/add them   to mentioned above txt file**

You are done with sql scripts' file.