# Import Tables from Derby File into Netbeans

Tags: java, database, netbeans, derby

**Question Background:** 
I created a Java database project using Apache Derby in Netbeans. I had to switch computers (I no longer have access to the old one), and when I did so, I was still able to run the project from Netbeans. However, when I checked the database setup, none of the tables were there. I'm assuming the program still works because the database configuration is still intact in the .netbeans-derby file.

**Question:**
My question is, **is there a way I can use the files in the .netbeans-derby to populate the database tables in Netbeans? Or do I need to create them all over again?** I figure I should be able to since the project works like nothing happened to the database. The table data must be somewhere, I am just not sure how to get to it.

**What I have tried:**
I've looked at some other questions. Most of them have to do with exporting a project with the database (like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709779/exporting-derby-database-in-netbeans)). That's how I came across the .netbeans-derby folder.

Comment: It sounds like you still have access to the old computer. Can you copy the database folder from the old computer to the new computer? Or can you get access to the old computer long enough to make a backup of the database on the old computer, then copy that backup to the new computer?

Comment: @BryanPendleton No, I don't have access to it anymore. I edited the question.